# Is copying only the prototype of EventEmitter is a good way of inheriting EventEmitter in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, prototypal-inheritance, eventemitter

I've been reading the `Nodejs in practice` book until I saw this example:

```js
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function MusicPlayer(track) {
  this.track = track;
  this.playing = false;

  for (var methodName in EventEmitter.prototype) {
    this[methodName] = EventEmitter.prototype[methodName];
  }
}
```

The author wrote that:*"This example might seem a little contrived, but sometimes it really is useful to copy EventEmitter’s properties rather than inherit from it in the usual way. This approach
is more akin to a mixin, or multiple inheritance; see this demonstrated in the following listing."*. But I just don't get it.

Although the example works like a charm, I can't help figuring it out whether this is a "good practice" to inherit classes in Js or not since the author only copied the `prototype` property of the EventEmitter class and completely ignore the properties instantiated inside the EventEmitter constructor which wonders me What would happen if I mistakenly invoke a method of the EventEmitter which depends on properties instantiated inside the EventEmitter constructor in order to run?

Suppose that all methods inside `prototype` of the EventEmitter are independent, is it a "good practice" to inherit classes in Js the way the author did in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventEmitter section in [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events) give the following example:

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});
myEmitter.emit('event');
```

So it is safe to say that this is the recommended approach. The [Prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) approach recommended by the author is an old way and not encouraged now.

Seems like what the author is trying to say is that it's good to inherit like this when there are multiple inheritance needed which is not allowed in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think the example in the document clear my question, since not only does the `extends` keyword copies methods inside the `prototype` property of the parent class, it also instantiates properties declared inside the parent class' constructor to the constructor of the inherited child class.

Comment: `extends` is literally a shortcut of doing what I believe to be the only good practice when it comes to inheriting in Js mentioned in the question I asked above

Comment: This is expected behavior and the "good practice" which was the original question. If you like a custom behavior feel free to copy all the methods in the prototype.

Comment: It is a good practice, it just doesn't answer my question. Btw, thank you for spending time answering my question. I appreciate it

Comment: It seems like the author of "Nodejs in practice" had a somewhat dogmatic approach to inheritance in JS. There are a lot of different ways of handling inheritance and composition in JS that have pros and cons in different situations. Fortunately with `class __ extends __` we now have a standardized way. I think the only time it would be helpful to manually copy EventEmitter properties would be a special case where you're already inheriting from some other class (which isn't an EventEmitter) but you want your subclass to be an EventEmitter as well.

Comment: Taking a quick look back, I realize that the author did mention that there're some cases EventEmitter can be inherited by copying its methods & this approach only work with EventEmitter(those this is not explicitly mentioned in the book)